# Not able to scroll and select cells displayed in uisearch controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I have a screen which shows favourite locations and if a user wants to add new location he can search using uisearchcontroller and add it to favourite location's list.

The problem is that once i make the api call for autocomplete the list of searched locations is visible but i cannot select or scroll the table.

I know that the problem is where i set the uisearchcontroller. but i do not know the right way to do it.
I am newbie in iOS so ur suggestions will be welcome.

the following is the [GithubRepository](https://github.com/shrsj/WeatherApp/tree/trial) for the project(incase ul want to try out the app and make suggestions)

> and heres the related code where i beleive the problem exists.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    favList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    searchList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    self.table.delegate = self;
    [self initSearch];
}
#pragma mark UI Search methods

-(void) initSearch
{
    FavouriteViewController *searchResultsController =  [[FavouriteViewController alloc] init];
    searchResultsController.table.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsController.table.delegate = self;
    searchResultsController.table.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    searchResultsController.table.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.search = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
    self.table.tableHeaderView = self.search.searchBar;
    self.search.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.search.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

}
```

> didSelectRowAtIndex method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.search.active) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObjectModel *place = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSString *places =[searchList[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
        if (![favList containsObject:places])
        {
            NSString *lati = [searchList[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lat"];
            NSString *longi = [searchList[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lon"];
            if (places != NULL && lati != NULL && longi != NULL)
            {
                [place setValue:places forKey:@"placeName"];
                [place setValue:lati forKey:@"latitude"];
                [place setValue:longi forKey:@"longitude"];
            }
            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
        [self.search setActive:NO];
        filtered = NO;
        [self getalldata];
        [self.table reloadData];

    }
    else
    {
        NSManagedObject *device = [favList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.SJI.Weather-App"];
        [defaults setObject:[device valueForKey:@"placeName"] forKey:@"favSet"];
        [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: so u r saying, did select method didn't get called when u select any cell ? Does the breakpoint hit at if(self.search.active) ?

Comment: yes it doesnt get called.. the problem is not on did select it mostly on the init search method

Comment: try to call the initsearch in viewDidAppear